# transform epoch milliseconds in long to timestamp type while ingestion in Druid

Tags: druid

My input data contains multiple fields which have epoch data in milliseconds in long datatype format. I want to transform format them into timestamp in Druid while ingestion. There are some time functions in the doc - https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/misc/math-expr.html. But I am not able to achieve the desired result. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Druid represents timestamps as milliseconds since the epoch, so there is nothing you need to do during ingestion - just add those fields as dimensions.  You can use those time functions when querying, in order to return the timestamps in any desired format.

As described in [the documentation](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/schema-design.html#secondary-timestamps):

> If your data has more than one timestamp, you can ingest the others as secondary timestamps. The best way to do this is to ingest them as [long-typed dimensions](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/ingestion-spec.html#dimensionsspec) in milliseconds format. If necessary, you can get them into this format using a [`transformSpec`](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/ingestion-spec.html#transformspec) and [expressions](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/misc/math-expr.html) like `timestamp_parse`, which returns millisecond timestamps.
>
> At query time, you can query secondary timestamps with [SQL time functions](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql-scalar.html#date-and-time-functions) like `MILLIS_TO_TIMESTAMP`, `TIME_FLOOR`, and others. If you're using native Druid queries, you can use [expressions](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/misc/math-expr.html).